# Connecting to Database in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2012

The Problem is: in Con.Open();

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

```
       protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string  Name = txtUsername.Text;
    string Pass = txtPass.Text;
    string Email = txtEmail.Text;


    ConnectionStringSettings settings;
    settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
    string connectionString = settings.ConnectionString;



    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Users values('" + Name + "','" + Pass + "','" + Email + "')", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



    con.Close(); 
}
```

and That is my Connection String in web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myData.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

how do i know exactly what is my Data source? and what seems to be the problem?
Thanks in Advcance.

Comment: Try http://www.connectionstrings.com/ - if you use SQL Server Express, you can refer to your server as .\SQLEXPRESS (I usually don't attach the way you're referencing in your connection string)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it can't connect to your database or instance of SQL SERVER. Have you try connecting to the db via SQl Server Management Studio?  if you can connect with SSMS, then your problem may be inside your connection string.

Also, get in the habit of using parameters for your sql statement.